# Converter for em while

Tags: c, for, while

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void) {

   int X[10], cont;
   cont=0;
   while(cont<10){
        printf("Digite um numero inteiro: ");
        scanf("%d",&X[cont]);
        if(X[cont] %2 == 0){
            X[cont]=0;
        }else{
            X[cont]=1;

        }
        cont++;
    }
    
   while(cont<10){
        printf(" %d ", X[cont]);
        cont++;
   }

    
}
```

Esse código não está funcionando, porém quando faço com `for` dá certo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void) {

   int X[10], cont;
   for(cont=0;cont<10;cont++){
        printf("Digite um numero inteiro: ");
        scanf("%d",&X[cont]);
        if(X[cont] %2 == 0){
            X[cont]=0;
        }else{
            X[cont]=1;

        }
    }
    
   for(cont=0;cont<10;cont++){
        printf(" %d ", X[cont]);
   }

    
}
```

Comment: Note que ao final do primeiro while a variável `cont` estará com o valor 10 e portanto não entrará no segundo loop. Reinicie a variável antes de entrar no segundo loop.

Comment: Ok, obrigada. Deu certo!

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

O principal problema é que não está zerando o contador quando vai fazer o segundo laço, como a variável estava valando 10 na saída do primeiro ele vai pegar posições erradas da memória na sequência. Aproveitei para organizar e simplificar o código.

Note que o resultado da conta para descobrir se é par ou ímpar já dá exatamente o número necessário, então não tem porque fazer um `if`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   int X[10];
   int cont = 0;
   while (cont < 10) {
        printf("Digite um numero inteiro: ");
        scanf("%d", &X[cont]);
        X[cont] = X[cont] % 2;
        cont++;
    }
    cont = 0;
    while (cont < 10) printf(" %d ", X[cont++]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/0zLKqD). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/drtrmnji-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/ZeroingCounter.c).

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigada!!

Comment: Como eu faço para verificar a posição de um vetor?

Comment: Teste fazer, se tiver algum problema faça uma nova pergunta com todos detalhes necessários.

Comment: Veja o [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado.